# Сайт с анкетами

Tags: python, веб-программирование, excel

нужно сделать сайт для учебного заведения с возможностью заполнения анкет, редактирования и выгрузки полученной инфы в Excel (для учителей), подскажите как лучше сделать и на каком лучше языке (python? С html и css все понятно)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

язык особой разницы не играет, практически у всех есть библиотеки для работы exсel файлами. Но если все же будите писать на Python, то вот вам библиотека для работы с exсel файлами - openpyxl. И [небольшая статейка](https://habr.com/ru/company/otus/blog/331998/) .